# aws KMS mocking node js

Tags: amazon-web-services, mocking

I am trying to mock KMS in node js using aws sdk mock but for me it is not at all mocking . It makes a call to real KMS and gets the actual encrypted key.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk-mock');
const params = {
    CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(someEncryptedKey, 'base64')
};
AWS.mock('KMS', 'decrypt', function (params, callback) {
    callback(null, new Buffer('116')[37, 80, 68, 56, 78, 87]);
});
```

I am not sure what wrong in my code. I could not find any good examples of mocking KMS. I can try Sinon but I do not want to because this ideally should do the magic of mocking. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here in the test. The problem is with mocking when you try to mock and your API version is globally declared in your code, you see this issue.

I just moved the version declaration in the actual code within the function. I do not have the answer why this is happening but after moving the API version within function mocking started working.

I never love changing the code for the unit test but with AWS SDK mock I had to do it.

const encryptDecrypt = async key => {

// this needs to be inside a function
// if this is globally declared and you try to write unit test for it, never works.
  const kms = new AWS.KMS({apiVersion: '2014-11-01'});

//    encrypt

// decrypr
};